# Why isn't Hallel recited on VE Day?

Tags: calendar, hallel, holocaust-shoah

There is a good deal of controversy about reciting Hallel on days not ordained by ancient tradition.  But there are at least [some opinions](http://www.vbm-torah.org/chanuka/hallel.htm) that Hallel should be recited to commemorate dates of national salvation.

Considering that the Holocaust resulted in the deaths of 6 million Jews, predominantly Ashkenazim, but many Sepharadim as well, why don't we mark the Nazis' unconditional surrender on 25 Iyar, the Hebrew date of 8 May 1945, the effective date of Nazi surrender by reciting Hallel?

Comment: Was the miracle in Israel?

Comment: @double there may be an answer there, but it seems at least plausible (if far fetched) that we should either recite Hallel or read the terms of surrender in a public forum, once in the evening, once during the day.

Comment: Israel was in the theater of the war, but if Purim does not count as including Israel, VE day shouldn't either.

Comment: As a "devil's advocate", how was there a nes in the establishment of Israel? One could easily argue that the chayalim were better led and had better commanders.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, one opinion is that Hallel is fulfilled by Mikra Megillah.

Comment: @noach, whom are you addressing?

Comment: @SethJ, I am addressing Clint Eastwood and Double AA.

Answer (score 1):

[Why do we not say Hallel on Purim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/why-do-we-not-say-hallel-on-purim?rq=1)

It says in Megilla 14a that one of the reasons why Purim you do not say hallel is.

"The miracle had no connection to the land of Israel, unlike the other holidays."

(Look at the Gemorah or the link for more reasons why you do not say hallel on Purim which can connect to this question.)

Comment: That's one opinion. Another, however, is that we *should* say it but fulfill it with the Megillah.

Answer (score 0):

Hallel is only for open miracles, not mere salvation. 12 Million Allied soldiers attacking from 2 fronts + partisans does not go against ordinary laws of physics.

Comment: You got a source?

Comment: And did you read the article at the link in my question?

Comment: Yes. Open Miracle and Salvation are treated as two different categories though no example of salvation exists in the Torah without a miracle. It is the overlap that resolves the issue of Purim. I heard a talk about it last Shavuot.